# How to make reference type as nullable in c# 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How make reference type as  nullable in c#4.0.

In c#8.0 we can make reference type as nullable.
But how to achieve this in c#4.0?

Comment: You have to create your own class with a null flag in it and check the nullable value from there. You will not be able to pass a null but a instanced class/object with a null flag in it.

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Can you give an example? In C# 4.0, every reference type is nullable.

Comment: @Luaan But that is a different "nullable" than the one you get in C# 8, though. I assume that's what's behind this question.

Comment: @Franck That's still not actually what you can do in C# 8. For example: have the compiler spit if you declared your reference as "can be null" but missed a spot, where you do not check or the opposite where you declare your reference as "cannot be null" and try to assign null to it.

Answer (score 7):

Reference types are **always nullable** in C#

In C#8 they added a feature called "*Nullable reference type*" to warn you when you don't check for null your variables

However, you can achieve similar null-safety warnings on other versions of C# by using a extension for VisualStudio called **[ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)** (it's not free)

Details on how it deals with null-checking you can find [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Detect_possible_NullReferenceExceptions.html)

Comment: For reference (no pun intended): [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

Comment: Anyhow, a complete answer would also cover _"But how to achieve this in c#4.0?"_ ...

Comment: How to achieve warnings at absence null checking? **ReSharper** does that partially

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58802172/edit) your answer to add info / improve it.